# Electrs server setup for local network

Tags: bitcoind, electrum-server

I have a machine (192.168.1.66) on a local network serving Electrs that's syncd to the tip (netstat -ntlp shows that electrs listening on 127.0.0.1:50001). But I have another machine (192.168.1.68) using SparrowWallet/ElectrumWallet that cannot connect to the machine hosting Electrs (e.g ./ElectrumWallet --server 192.168.1.66:50001:t will not connect/ SparrowWallet shows connection refused), what could be the problem? I am also wondering if using electrs as a trezor backend requires encryption or it can be running unencrypted

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add this into your Electrum Server config file:

```
electrum_rpc_addr="0.0.0.0:50001"
```

Comment: I assume you meant the config file provided when you start up the electrs binary (which is in my ~/.electrs/electrs.config) but I did make that change and it didn't seem to help

Comment: @BillyT Did you restarted the electrs after the change, right? Weird, I had a similar issue and this fixed for me. What is the output of this command on the other machine `$ telnet 192.168.1.66 50001`?

Comment: Unable to connect to remote host: connection refused for telnet on a different device. Though on the same machine hosting electrs I can `telnet 127.0.0.1 50001` and connect

Comment: Sure, on the same machine it should work. Are you running any firewall like ufw or something like that? If so, enable the port

Comment: I do not have ufw installed, I just have a fresh ootb installation of debian12. I installed ufw and `sudo ufw allow 50001/tcp` but it made no difference

Comment: No luck either with iptables `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 50001 -j ACCEPT` still gives me connection:refused

Comment: I found the problem, such a stupid mistake. The systemd service I had was running arguments in the execution path which overwrote the config I supplied so nothing was changing, it works fine with 0.0.0.0:50001, however now I am trying to connect but it's taking a very long time and ends up with `Retries exhuasted` at least for sparrow wallet, the machine is pretty horrible (old random laptop that even lags when rdp'd into) I assume this is just a hardware problem?